# Angular8 Reactive Forms -How to handle the checkbox controls(same) when there are multiple forms having these checkboxes inside

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a scenario.When user clicks on + button, same form gets replicated.All the fields are same so iam using ngFor.I have used checkboxes in the form.
I have problem with checkbox controls in each form,getting the values of checkboxes.

[image: screenshot]

Now for one form it is ok, we have one function

`get socialsArray(){
     return <FormArray>this.primaryForm.get('socialcontrol');
  }`

But when i click + button, formgroup is generated dynamically but i cant generate above "get function" like
`get socialsArray(){
    return <FormArray>this."dynamicallygeneratedformgroup".get('socialcontrol');
}`

Im using socialsArray for this.

HTML:

```
<label *ngFor="let social of socialsArray.controls;let i=index;" 
class="kt- 
 checkbox">
 <input (change)="updateCheckboxList(secondaryForm)" 
[formControl]="social" 
 type="checkbox" id="secform{{socials[i].name}}"> {{socials[i].name}}
 <span></span>
 </label>
```

TS:

```
 this.primaryForm=return this.formBuilder.group({
  firstname:['',Validators.required],
  lastname:['',Validators.required],
  socialcontrol:this.addSocialControls()
})

addSocialControls(){
const arr = this.socials.map(item => {
  return this.formBuilder.control(false);
});
 return this.formBuilder.array(arr);
}
```

I tried to create a formgrouparray and rewrite the function as

```
getSocialsArray(formgroup){
return <FormArray>formgroup.get('socialcontrol'); 
}
```

and in html

```
*ngFor="let social of socialsArray.controls(index);let i=index;"
```

But it returns error

[image]

Comment: you need to push form control into the form array

Comment: not clear andrew

Comment: See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plp4rb-formarray-total-16z24o?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftotal-calculator%2Ftotal-calculator.component.ts) - notice how initial form has `lines: this.fb.array([])` and `addLineFormGroup` pushes form group onto the form array. You can make `getLineFormGroup` take optional data for when you are initializing the form.

Comment: ok but the real problem is in this function  get socialControls() ...its gives error if i give parameter to it

Comment: what function? also you question does not include `updateCheckboxList`

Comment: sorry it was not meaningful function name...that function i created to count the number of checkboxes selected(only count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you has severals "students", so you can has an array of FormGroups -not a formArray-

```
primaryForm:FormGroup[]=[]
```

Really you has a function createForm that return a formGroup

```
createFormGroup():FormGroup{
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    firstname:['',Validators.required],
    lastname:['',Validators.required],
    socialcontrol:this.addSocialControls()
  })
}
```

To ask for the formArray, you add an index

```
get socialsArray(index){
   return <FormArray>this.primaryForm[index].get('socialcontrol');
}
```

At ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.primaryForm.push(this.createFormGroup())
}
```

And your .html

```
<div *ngFor="let formGroup of primaryForm;let index=index">
   <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
     <input formGroupName="firstname">
     <input formGroupName="lastname">
     <!--here your array, see how use "index"-->
     <label *ngFor="let social of socialsArray(index).controls;let i=index;"
       class="kt-checkbox">
       <!--To know what check, pass as argumnet "index" too-->
       <input (change)="updateCheckboxList(index,secondaryForm)" 
              [formControl]="social" 
           type="checkbox" id="secform{{socials[i].name}}"> {{socials[i].name}}
          <span></span>
     </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: I don't understand your function updateCheckboxList(index,secondaryForm). In general, in ReactiveForms it's prefer use

```
primaryForm[index].get('social').valueChanges
    .subscribe(res=>{
       //here you has the array of values
    })
```

Well, really need make some thing like

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.primaryForm.push(this.createFormGroup())
 this.primaryForm[0].get('social').valueChanges
    .subscribe(res=>{
       //here you has the array of values
    })
}
```

And, when add a new form

```
addForm()
{
  this.primaryForm.push(this.createFormGroup())
 this.primaryForm[this.primaryForm.length-1].get('social').valueChanges
    .subscribe(res=>{
       //here you has the array of values
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, but i tried----- get socialsArray(index){
   return <FormArray>this.primaryForm[index].get('socialcontrol');
} it says get accessor cannot have parameters ..its not working

Comment: you need subscribe to valueChanges, after create the formArray, I forget the "this", I updated the answer